# Serializing Data

Tags: .net, serialization

How do I serialize an array of characters to a file? The whole reason I'm doing it is so that you can't just open up the file and edit the data but what I'm about to tell you shows otherwise. I create an array of characters and set `arr[0]` to 'a', `arr[1]` to 'b', and `arr[2]` to 'c'. I then use .NET to serialize the array. I run it, open the file and it reads this:
[image]

As stated above I don't want someone to just open up the file and edit the data but this clearly shows it's possible.

Code:

```
arr[0] = 'a';
arr[1] = 'b';
arr[2] = 'c';

FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath+"/testing.wld", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

bFormatter.Serialize(stream, arr);
stream.Close();
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You will have to encode the data somehow if you don't want the characters to be recognizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not asking about serialization. You are asking about obfuscating / schiffering / more advanced sollutions.

If you want to use the built-in serialize classes in .NET you will have to implemented your own (XML)Writer/Reader - implement a obfuscating routine of choice in this function and make sure its 1:1.

But it will of course not be "safe", just delay the penetrator for a while.

Comment: Forgive me for my arrogance but I would like the data to be stored as bytes so the file size is small. I know that one ANSCII character is a byte however encoding it or obfuscating it or whatever won't be an ANSCII character. I guess what I'm asking is can you have a regular file and a encoded file with the same information be the same size? Maybe I should start a new question but it seems to simple.

Comment: schiffering doesn't nec. add to the file size. for instance Byte1 XOR Byte 2 is still one byte large.